# Streamreader adds Column with opened File Dialog

Tags: c#, streamreader, openfiledialog

in the following code I want to have my OpenFileDialog open in a method until a valid file is selected. This works only conditionally. For some reason it adds a column after the message is displayed. This causes correct data tables to also be read incorrectly if I have previously selected an incorrect file.

```
public static InputData GetCSVData()
        {
            InputData InputData = new InputData();

            OpenFileDialog OFDReader = new OpenFileDialog();

            //Filter OpenFileDialog; show only CSV-Files
            OFDReader.Filter = "CSV files|*.csv;";

            // check if data contains "Date/Time" .
            OFDReader.FileOk += delegate (object s, CancelEventArgs ev)

            {                                 
                //search for Line to start reader
                int LineCounter = 0;
                var readertmp = new StreamReader(OFDReader.FileName);
                while (true)
                {
                    string LineTmp = readertmp.ReadLine();
                    string record = "Date/Time";
                    if (LineTmp.Contains(record))
                    { break; }
                    else if (readertmp.EndOfStream)
                    {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data has no DataPoints !", "Wrong Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                        ev.Cancel = true; 
                        { break; }
                    }
                    LineCounter++;
                }

                 //read InputData
                 var reader = new StreamReader(OFDReader.FileName);
                 for (int i = 0; i < LineCounter; i++)
                 {
                 reader.ReadLine();
                 }
                 // settings CSVHelper
                 var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                 {
                    Delimiter = ";", // Set delimiter
                 };

                var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config);
                var DataRead = new CsvDataReader(csv);
                InputData.DataTable.Load(DataRead);

                //check for enough columns
                int ColumnCounter = 0;
                ColumnCounter = InputData.DataTable.Columns.Count;
                if (ColumnCounter <= 2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data has not enough columns!", "Wrong Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    ev.Cancel = true;
                }
            };

            if (OFDReader.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                InputData.FilePath = OFDReader.FileName;
            }

            return InputData;

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are making this more complicated than it has to be. For starters it seems odd (at least to me) that you would bother with the `FileOK` delegate. I do not see what difference it would make if the user is presented with an `OpenFileDialog` once, twice or many times. Using a single `OpenFileDialog` for this just seems like a waste of effort.

If the user selects a file and it fails to meet the necessary requirements, then simply open another `OpenFileDialog` and let the user try again. Doing this in a single dialog is certainly possible, however, “where” else would you use this? It appears this dialog is “specific” to a “certain” type of file, why limit the dialog to the requirement we need. I would think a simple method that loops forever until the user selects a valid file or Cancels the `OpenFileDialog` would be an easier approach.

With that said, following your code is a little odd. The reason for your issue is that the code is reading the file into the `InputData.DataTable` regardless if the file FAILS having datapoints OR enough columns. Put a breakpoint on the line…

```
InputData.DataTable.Load(DataRead);
```

You will see that the `DataTable` is filled with the data even if the data has no “DataPoints.” After the above line of code executes the next few lines check to see if the `DataTable` has 2 or more columns of data. If there are not enough columns, then the code simply pops up a message box indicating this.

This appears straight forward, however, the `InputData.DataTable` STILL HAS THE DATA even if it was bad. Next time you call the above Load method, it will simply ADD the new table to the existing table. It will add the columns if needed and simply add the rows to the bottom of the existing `DataTable`. Try opening several BAD files then eventually open the good file and you will see many added columns and rows.

I will assume that you may be under the impression that when you call…

```
ev.Cancel = true;
```

That the code stops right there and goes back to the first line in the delegate…

```
int LineCounter = 0;
```

… this would not be true. The code continues after `ev.Cancel = true;` is executed.

This can be seen by the fact that you are getting extra columns and rows every time a BAD file is attempted to be opened. A simple solution is to simply create a “new” `InputData` object just before you call the load method. Something like…

```
InputData = new InputData();
InputData.DataTable.Load(DataRead);
```

This will fix the extra columns issue, however, IF the user selects a BAD file and the error message pops up and the user clicks the OK button to go back to the open file dialog… THEN… IF the user then clicks the open file dialogs “Cancel” button, the BAD file will still be displayed in the grid. I am confident you may not want this behavior.

Without going into detail about some of the other strange aspects of the posted code. I proffer one other possible simpler solution as described in the beginning. Granted, the code below uses multiple `OpenFileDialog`s, however the user still cannot escape until they pick a valid file or cancel the dialog.

Much of the code below is taken from the existing posted code however, it is structured differently. Initially some variables are created before we stat an endless loop. Specifically, the `CsvConfiguration` variable `config` has some added properties set that ignore some code crashing problems when reading the file. I am confident you will want to set up the `CsvReader` to handle these problems the way you want them to be handled.

Once inside the endless `while` loop, the code creates a new `InputData` object, initializes a new `OpenFileDialog` and sets its properties. Then the code displays the `OpenFileDialog` and when the dialog returns, the `DialogResult` `result` variable is set to the dialogs returned `DialogResult`.

If the dialog returns `OK` then the code checks to see if the file is an “empty” file. If the file is empty, a message box is displayed to inform the user, then we branch back up to the begging of the loop. If the dialog result is `Cancel`, then the code will return a “new” `InputData` object. The reason for the empty check is that an exception (No header record was found) will be throw on the line…

```
DataRead = new CsvDataReader(csv);
```

If the file is empty.

I am confident that there may be some `CsvHelper` property that I missed that would prevent this “empty” file exception. If there is some better way to check for this “empty” file or prevent the exception, I am open to suggestions.

If the file is NOT empty, we continue by opening the file and go ahead and read its data as intended using the `CsvDataReader`. The idea is that… IF the file reads correctly without errors and fits the requirements, then we will already have the `InputData.DataTable` set and all that is left to do is to set its `FilePath` property and return the `InputData` object.

Once we have the `InputData.DataTable` we can check the number of columns in the `InputData.DataTable`. If the number of columns is less than two (2), then pop up the error message box to the user and loop back to the begging of the `while` loop.

If the `InputData.DataTable` meets the two (2) or more columns requirement, then another check is made by looping through all the columns in the data table. If at least ONE (1) column name is “Date/Time” then we are done checking the requirements and simply set the `InputData.FileName` property and return the `InputData` object.

If none of the column names in the `InputData.DataTable` columns is named ”Date/Time,” then again we pop up the error message box and loop back to the begging of the `while` loop.

It should be noted that if the file fails the number of columns test or the column named `Date/Time` test… then as with your problem, the `InputData.DataTable` STILL HAS THE DATA. This is OK here since we will re-initialize a “new” `InputData` object when we loop back up to the begging of the `while` loop.

Lastly, you do not show the `InputData` Class, however it appears to have at least two (2) properties… 1) a `string` `FilePath` and 2) a `DataTable` named `DataTable`??? this looks odd and is ambiguous… I have renamed my `InputData` object’s `DataTable` property to `DT`. The same “ambiguity” applies to the `InputData` variable which I have changed to `TempInputData`.

Since the code may “potentially” create numerous `InputData` objects each time the user selects a BAD file, I have implemented the `IDisposable` interface in the `InputData` Class. This way we can use this Class in a `using` statement and properly dispose of the unused `InputData` objects the code creates. I hope I have implemented this correctly.

```
public class InputData : IDisposable {

  public DataTable DT;
  public string FilePath;
  private bool isDisposed;

  public InputData() {
    DT = new DataTable();
    FilePath = "";
  }

  public void Dispose() {
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
    if (isDisposed) {
      return;
    }
    if (disposing) {
      DT?.Dispose();
      FilePath = null;
    }
    isDisposed = true;
  }
}


private InputData GetInputDataFromSCV() {
  InputData TempInputData;
  OpenFileDialog OFDReader;
  string initialDirectory = @"D:\Test\CSV";
  DialogResult result;
  CsvConfiguration config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) {
    Delimiter = ";",
    IgnoreBlankLines = true,
    MissingFieldFound = null,
    BadDataFound = null
  };
  CsvReader csv;
  CsvDataReader DataRead;
  StreamReader readertmp;
  FileInfo fi;
  while (true) {
    using (TempInputData = new InputData()) {
      using (OFDReader = new OpenFileDialog()) {
        OFDReader.Filter = "CSV files|*.csv;";
        OFDReader.InitialDirectory = initialDirectory;
        result = OFDReader.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
          fi = new FileInfo(OFDReader.FileName);
          if (fi.Length != 0) {
            using (readertmp = new StreamReader(OFDReader.FileName)) {
              csv = new CsvReader(readertmp, config);
              DataRead = new CsvDataReader(csv);
              TempInputData.DT.Load(DataRead);
              if (TempInputData.DT.Columns.Count > 2) {
                foreach (DataColumn column in TempInputData.DT.Columns) {
                  if (column.ColumnName == "Date/Time") {
                    TempInputData.FilePath = OFDReader.FileName;
                    return TempInputData;
                  }
                }
                // if we get here we know a column named "Date/Time" was NOT found
                MessageBox.Show("Data has no DataPoints !", "Wrong Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
              }
              else {
                MessageBox.Show("Data has less than 2 columns?", "Wrong Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
              }
            }
          }
          else {
            MessageBox.Show("File is empty!", "Wrong Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
          }
        }
        else {
          if (result == DialogResult.Cancel) {
            return new InputData();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: I haven't tried your code yet, but thanks for the detailed answer. I also had the idea with the new input, still errors came through as you described. 
I am not looking for a "date/time" column in my code, but a specific row. The CSV file has unspecified rows at the beginning, which I don't need. Only the values from "Date/Time" are relevant.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have adapted it to my code and it works fine. I just have a small question, my streamreader recognizes 4 or 2 characters in an empty file. I think it has something to do with the defaults in Excel. I got around it by setting your rule with fi.Length != 0 in Fi.Length >= 10. IgnoreBlankLines is related to CSVconfig.

Comment: Hello, it's been a little while but somehow the following is giving me trouble. I want to keep the data when canceling if any file was successfully read before. 
Otherwise further calculations will not work and the Cancel Button works as a hard reset.

Comment: Sorry, but can you clarify what you mean by… _”I want to keep the data when canceling if any file was successfully read before.”_ … ? …

Comment: I have attached getinputdatafro to a button. This allows me to read certain values and use them for the calculations. 
If I now want to load another file and cancel in the input dialog, the tempiputdata is read with 0. I would like to be able to continue calculating with the previously loaded values. How can I work around this or avoid that he passes on zero if there are already data. 
Furthermore, if someone wants to read in new data, this class should remain as it is.

Comment: Well… I am still not following exactly what you are asking. I suggest you create a new question and detail what you are wanting to do and what is not working. You can tag me with your new question and I will try to help. From what I can gather it sounds like you need to save the data from the previous read. Currently the code uses only one (1) table and deletes the previous data, so it is sounds like you may want to save that data and use a new table. Again this is just a guess. Your best bet is to make another question.

Comment: First, thank you for the quick responses. And you got me right. I want to save the table from previous reads if they cancel. Even if I made a 2nd Datatable the whole class is disposed after the Inputdialog.Cancel. Your suggestion was great to make it disposeable so that bad files are deleted. Somehow i couldnt logically work around this. I hope i could clarify my question a bit more. I even tried to make a new class, so i can use it as Cachedata. It made no sense, since it reads the zero after this class is disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry for the inconvenience. Sometimes I really make it too complicated for myself. I have now solved it as follows:

```
 if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
 {
   if (inputDataHistory.Loadcount != 0)
    {
       TempInputData.FilePath = inputDataHistory.FilePathCache;
       TempInputData.LineCounter = inputDataHistory.LinecounterCache;


       var reader = new StreamReader(TempInputData.FilePath);
       for (int i = 0; i < TempInputData.LineCounter; i++)
             {
                  reader.ReadLine();
             }
              csv = new CsvReader(reader, config);
              DataRead = new CsvDataReader(csv);
              TempInputData.DT.Load(DataRead);
              TempInputData.IsDisposed = true;
              return TempInputData;
   }
      else
           {
            return new InputData();
           }
```

I don't know if it is the most efficient solution but I read the key variables into another class before. These are used when canceling to re-read the file before.